# Do NPC companions level up when they are not in the party?

Tags: fallout-2

Companions in Fallout 2 level up with you, but what if they are put on hold and then recruited again? Do they gain levels automatically to match my own or do I have to level them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they don't.

They level at random* approximately every 3 levels but they only have a chance to level up  if they are in your party when you level.

*The chance is based on how long since they last leveled so you they level at least +1 for each +3 you do, but only if you have them with you.